# function calling from another function javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 functions. `First` contains Jquery-UI dialog and called from the `Second` function. Something like :

```
function First() {
    $('div').dialog({
        buttons: {
            "Ok": function () { /* code */
            }
        }
    });
}

function Second() {
    First();
    /* rest of this function code is depend upon the "Ok button" 
       function code */
}
```

Now my problem is that after calling function `First` the execution of script doesn't wait for `dialog's Ok button press`. Whats should i do, so that only after pressing the `Ok button`, the control return from the function `First`?

Comment: Use the callback option of OK button

Comment: Write that code in OK function

Comment: move the code after `first` function call in `second` function to `OK button click `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move from the function `Second` the part after calling `First` into a 2nd function (here called `SecondOkHandler`). Call `First` with a new parameter (this callback function) and in the function `First` on 'ok' call this:

```
function First(okCallback) {
    $('div').dialog({ 
        buttons : {
            "Ok" : okCallback
        }
    });
}

function Second () {
    First(SecondOkHandler);
}

function SecondOkHandler() {
    /* rest of this function code is depend upon the "Ok button" function code */
}
```

Also see [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/HD5V8/1/).

=== UPDATE ===

To make it more complex, here [a link to an example](http://jsfiddle.net/HD5V8/3/) with more callbacks.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have given a parenthesis `First()`  this will make a call to that function as soon as the parser encounter that line.

You can make use of the one of the 2 Javascript methods of calling the function [`apply`](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2007/07/05/function-apply-and-function-call-in-javascript.aspx) or [`call`](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2007/07/05/function-apply-and-function-call-in-javascript.aspx). By using this your function will not execute as soon it is encounter.

Check out this reference http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2007/07/05/function-apply-and-function-call-in-javascript.aspx

Try using this and let me know if it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

```
    function First(waitTillOk) {
        $('div').dialog({
            buttons: {
                "Ok": function () { 
                      /* code */
                      if(typeof waitTillOk == "function"){
                        waitTillOk();
                      }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    function Second() {
        var waitTillOk = function(){
         /* rest of this function code is depend upon the "Ok button" 
           function code */
     }
     First(waitTilOk);
    }
```